# Trying to edit a Host file n a windows machine, trying to find out where it is located?

Tags: windows, host

Trying to edit a host file on my Windows 7 machine, can't seem to to find it in the system 32 folder?

Comment: Might be a better question for SuperUser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's located inside of

```
C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc
```

Answer (score 1):

The `hosts` file is located on the `%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc` folder:

usually `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc`.

This is valid for every Windows version since Windows XP, either 32 or 64 bits.

Answer (score 1):

You might have the Windows Explorer Folder Options set to "Don't show hidden files, folders, or drives" which prevents you to see the hosts file.

To fix that and Show the hidden files do:

1. Open Windows Explorer. click "Alt" button to bring up the File menu if you don't see it. Click on "Tools" and then "Folder Options..."
2. Click on the "View" tab and enable the radio button "Show hidden files, folders, and drives"

[image: Folder Options]

After that for a quick browse to the location do:
Start-> Run-> %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\

[image: Hosts File]

Run as Administrator your file editor in order to make changes to the hosts file

[image]